# Not all text is being displayed when using on-screen keypad

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Created a keypad in Flash cs6 following a tutorial. Once done the "1" key and the "4" key work--those numbers show up in the display. The rest of the numbers, however, do not. For example, if I click the 1, 2, 3, and 4 buttons the display only shows "14" instead of "1234". I put a "trace" line of code on each button to see if they are at least being recognized when I click on them...all of the buttons apparently work.

The code:

```
stop();

var displayText:String = "";


function numDisplay(num:String)
{
    displayText += num;
    displayNum.text = displayText;
}

key1bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey1);
function pressedKey1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    numDisplay("1");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key2bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey2);
function pressedKey2(event:MouseEvent):void{
    numDisplay("2");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key3bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey3);
function pressedKey3(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("3");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key4bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey4);
function pressedKey4(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("4");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key5bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey5);
function pressedKey5(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("5");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key6bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey6);
function pressedKey6(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("6");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key7bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey7);
function pressedKey7(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("7");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key8bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey8);
function pressedKey8(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("8");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key9bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey9);
function pressedKey9(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("9");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}

key0bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pressedKey0);
function pressedKey0(event:MouseEvent):void {
    numDisplay("0");
    trace(displayNum.text);
}
```

Thanks, appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: You didn't do any mistake, maybe you use a special font, so you must embed it

Comment: That happens if you select "Embed Fonts" option in the **TextField** but don't actually go check the character ranges, so Flash compiler ends up embedding only those characters you occasionally left in the text fields and any text is displayed in a weird subset of characters.